# CsvHelper Change DefaultClassMap Properties dynamically

Tags: csvhelper

I'm trying to change map fields in Default Class map dynamically.

**Consider Foo Class with 2 properties:**

1. Type
2. Value

**In my CSV I've 3 Fields:**

1. type
2. value1
3. value2

**I Created couple of Dictionaries like below:**

1. value1Mapping:  {Type, type},{Value, value1}
2. value2Mapping:  {Type, type},{Value, value2}

**Also, I created DefaultClassMap's like below:**

```
var value1Map = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();
value1Map.Map(value1Mapping);    
var value2Map = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();
value2Map.Map(value2Mapping);
```

**Finally, using Reading by hand, trying to read the data from CSV file:**

```
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(value1Mapping);
var value1Info = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();    
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(value2Mapping);
var value2Info = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
```

I'm getting value1Info same as value2Info even though value1, value2 in csv is different values.

As, we've csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(value1Mapping) initially, value1Info & value2Info is getting value1 values from csv

How we can use dynamic mappings for a same entity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the `ClassMap` for `Foo` in the middle of reading the records.  Once you start reading, the `ClassMap` gets cached and can't be changed.  What you could do, is only register `Foo.Type` and then dynamically read the value fields.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("type,value1,value2\nFooType,value1,value2"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var typeMap = "type";
        var value1Map = "value1";
        var value2Map = "value2";

        var fooMap = new DefaultClassMap<Foo>();
        fooMap.Map(m => m.Type).Name(typeMap);
        
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(fooMap);
        
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var foo1 = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
            foo1.Value = csv.GetField(value1Map);
            Console.WriteLine($"foo1Type: \"{foo1.Type}\", foo1Value: \"{foo1.Value}\"");
                
            var foo2 = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
            foo2.Value = csv.GetField(value2Map);
            Console.WriteLine($"foo2Type: \"{foo2.Type}\", foo2Value: \"{foo2.Value}\"");
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, for the response.
Currently, I'm using the same like "csv.GetField", but thought may be there could be some generic way.
I tried UnRegisterMap and everything, but didn't worked.

This make sense "the ClassMap gets cached and can't be changed."

Thanks a lot !!!